# How to calculate probability at a point from cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve $\mathbb P(X=0)$ of this question:

> [image]

We have $\mathbb P(X=0) = \mathbb P(X \le 0) - \mathbb P(X<0) =  F_X (0) - \mathbb P(X<0)$. I guess $\mathbb P(X<0) = 0$, but I'm unable to prove this from $F_X (t) = 0$ for all $t<0$.

Could you please shed me some light? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{X<0\}=\lim_{y\to 0^-}\mathbb P\{X\leq y\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can see that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X<0)= \mathbb{P}\Big(  \cup\{  X \leq -1/n \} \Big) = \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} \mathbb{P}(X\leq-1/n)=0 $$

Since $\{ X\leq -1/n \}$ are a sequence of increasing events.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, and also not generalizable to other cases.

Comment: I hope this revision is better.